# How to Android authentication and take data with Json?

Tags: android, json, post

I create projenct to android authentication with web services.I use post and json parsing to take data , I send to web servise username and pasword for authentication that take what I want to choose any infromation in pesponse data but whatever I did not successful to take what ı want to I think I make some mistake or forgot something.I want to login to web authentication  and after authentication ,How take What I want to specific information.

```
class Post extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    // Post tan önce yapılacak işlemler. Yükleniyor yazısını(ProgressDialog) gösterdik.
    JSONObject veri_json;
    JSONObject jsonobj;
    protected void  onPreExecute() {

        pDialog=new ProgressDialog(OgrenciBilgiSistemi.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);// ProgressDialog u iptal edilemez hale getirdik.
        pDialog.show();
    };
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {// Arka Planda yapılacaklar. Yani Post işlemi 

        //Post edilecek değişkenleri ayarliyoruz.
        List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", og_no.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", og_sifre.getText().toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept", "application/json"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-type", "application/json"));


        //PostClass daki httpPost metodunu çağırdık.Gelen string değerini aldık
        veri_string=post.httpPost(url, "POST", params, 2000);

        try {
            ////gelen veri_string değerini json arraye çeviriyoruz.
             //try içinde yapmak zorunlu çıkabilecek bir sorunda uygulamanın patlamaması için
            veri_json=new JSONObject(veri_string);




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // gelen veriyi log tuttuk
        Log.d("HTTP POST CEVAP:",""+ veri_string);
        return null;
    }
```

And I have Post Class

```
try {

        if (method == "POST") {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeout1 = time;
            int timeout2 = time;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout1);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout2);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            veri =  httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            veri =  httpEntity.getContent();            
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                veri, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        veri.close();
        veri_string = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Hata " + e.toString());
             }

    return veri_string; // Aldığımız cevabın string halini geri dönüyoruz

}
```

I take this pesponse
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date in onPostExecute
First create JSONobject myObject=new JSONobject(your json string from server)
then you can extract your arrays or inner json objects by calling my myObject.getJSONArray("name of the array"), myObject.getJSONObject("object name")
and then from these objects and arrays you can extract values by calling appropriate methods like getString getInt etc.
After extracting all this info store those values in SharedPreferences to use anywhere in your app.
Links for JSON parsing and SharedPreferences
[JSON parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Can you give me specific example @Krishna Teja Velagapudi

Comment: From the above json file you posted what do you want to extract. I can give you an example by extracting that text